# Django giving user the ability to manage files/images

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I need help understanding hot to go about giving my users the ability to upload and remove files in the same form.

Is there a demo some were i can find?

It seems a pretty redundant task but i cant find a documentation on that.

- Not talking about admin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 'in the same form'. Do you want to upload a new file while marking a already uploaded file as to-be-deleted?

You could put a list of existing files as MultipleChoiceField underneath your FileField and delete whichever the user selected as part of your form processing.

There is also a whole lot of 3rd party packages which might suit your needs:
https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/file-managers/

---

Since I can't comment yet.
You probably want to solve it with ajax requests

```
[___newfile.txt___] [browse] [add] --POST--> /add
 - File 1 [Trash] --GET--> /delete/1
 - File 2 [Trash]
 - File 3 [Trash]
 - File 1 [Trash]
```

Comment: What i'm trying to do until now is create a form_set based on current items thinking that will give the user unified experience on adding and removing files. 

But i think i'm missing something in the UX+Tech side of things. 

Your suggestion to separate the current from possible. That is what ppl doing usually?

Comment: most people would do it with ajax-requests I guess, one to post a new file, one to delete an existing one, I added it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! The issue for me was actually a UX thing. I needed to think/design the form differently. Just like you says show a table of existing and show a form for adding new ones.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a demo project to show how this works.
You can find it at https://github.com/trostik/djangoimagemanage

Hope it helps some one.

Cheers